# How to modify the argument of a specific function below?

Tags: functions, evaluation, hold, arguments, return-value

I would like to change the values of `a` and `b` in the following function:

```
SetAttributes{TrigIndices,HoldAll};
TrigIndices[j_, n_, a_, b_] :=
  (
   (* index "a" *)
   Which[
    j == n, a = 2,
    j == n - 1, a = 1,
    True, a = j - 1];

   (* index "b" *)
   Which[
    j > n - 2, b = 1,
    True, b = 0];
   );

TrigIndices[1, 5, a, b]
a
(* incorrect output: 0 *)
b
(* incorrect output: b *)
```

However, variables `a` and `b` have incorrect values after calling  `TrigIndices`.
Could you please help me what the problem is with this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to set variables in the way you're doing it. Passing variables "by reference" is an idea that comes from other programming languages (C and C++, for example).

Better to define functions, for example with

```
a[j_, n_] := Which[j == n, 2, j == n - 1, 1, True, j - 1]
b[j_, n_] := Which[j > n - 2, 1, True, 0]
```

and then use

```
a[1, 5]
(*    0    *)

b[4, 5]
(*    1    *)
```

Alternatively, work with [conditional patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) instead of `Which`:

```
Clear[a, b];
a[j_, n_] /; j == n = 2;
a[j_, n_] /; j == n - 1 = 1;
a[j_, n_] = j - 1;
b[j_, n_] /; j > n - 2 = 1;
b[j_, n_] = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, but it would be good to have `a` and `b` within the same structure. Can I form, for example, an ordered `(a,b)` pair somehow?

Comment: You can return a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of both: ``ab[j_, n_] := {Which[j == n, 2, j == n - 1, 1, True, j - 1], Which[j > n - 2, 1, True, 0]}``

Comment: Of course, you can define a function `ab[j_, n_] := {Which[j == n, 2, j == n - 1, 1, True, j - 1], Which[j > n - 2, 1, True, 0]}` that returns both at once: `ab[4, 5]` returns `{1, 1}`.

Comment: And how can I reference the first and second entries of `ab[4,5]` (that is, 1 and 1)? I would like to save them into local variables, say `f` and `s`.

Comment: You can assign a list of numbers to a list of variables: `{f, s} = ab[99, 233]`

Comment: OK, thanks. I have now accepted your answer. The first thing I wanted to try is this ordered-pair-based representation, but I did not find anything for how to implement this.